# How to set "concurency=X" for limiting number of concurrent workflows in Github Actions?

Tags: github-actions

I'm looking for a way to use concurrency != 1, i.e. I want to limit the number of concurrent workflows to 2 for example.
It seems to be a very trivial feature for CI platform, but I couldn't find a way to do that in Github Actions.

Thanks,
Vitaly

Comment: I don't think you can use concurrency for anything other than making sure only one workflow/job in the same concurrency group is running at the same time.

Comment: @BenjaminW. - thank you! 
Do you think I can limit the number of concurrent running workflows to X - using some other configurations?

Comment: Maybe with a `run` step where you use the GitHub CLI to fetch the number of currently active runs, and then bail out if necessary; something like `gh run list --workflow workflow.yml --json status` and then filter by the status for `in_progress`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this expression to limit 2 workflows that can be run at the same time

concurrency:
group: ${{ endsWith(github.run_number, '0') || endsWith(github.run_number, '2') || endsWith(github.run_number, '4') || endsWith(github.run_number, '6') || endsWith(github.run_number, '8') }}

Example:

```
name: Test Concurrency Limit 2 Workflows

on:
  workflow_dispatch:

concurrency:
  group: ${{ endsWith(github.run_number, '0') || endsWith(github.run_number, '2') || endsWith(github.run_number, '4') || endsWith(github.run_number, '6') || endsWith(github.run_number, '8') }}

env:
  TESTDATA: ${{ endsWith(github.run_number, '0') || endsWith(github.run_number, '2') || endsWith(github.run_number, '4') || endsWith(github.run_number, '6') || endsWith(github.run_number, '8') }}
  
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4
      - name: Show variables
        run: |
          echo "run_number: ${{ github.run_number }}"
          echo "TESTDATA: ${{ env.TESTDATA }}"
```

Comment: Thank you! 
I'm not sure I'll be able to test this soon, but your suggestion seems be very interesting!

Answer (score 1):

So currently (02.2023) neither Github Actions nor GitLab CI has this concurrency/throttling feature (in style of https://plugins.jenkins.io/throttle-concurrents/).

Resources:
https://forum.gitlab.com/t/is-there-support-for-throttling-concurrent-jobs/80973?u=vitalykarasik

https://github.com/community/community/discussions/45140